# Can't use vuex(npm packages) in nativescript playground

Tags: nativescript, vuex, nativescript-vue, nativescript-playground

I get error that vuex was not found but I've added the npm package and everything.

Here is the link to the [playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=Cr5A99&v=22)

Comment: Are you sure it was not some cache? It seem to work on my end.

Comment: @Manoj it is working for me now too. What should I do next time I get this "caching" problem?

Comment: It doesn't happen often but I have been there. I usually clear the Playground memory / storage, restart the app. It mostly fixes that.